# stack not 16 byte aligned error when mocking exit with mimick

Tags: c, macos, mocking, clang, llvm

I'm using [Mimick](https://github.com/Snaipe/Mimick) to mock the exit function, but I get a stack not 16 byte aligned error.

Here's a reduced code example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mimick.h>

mmk_mock_define(exit_mock, void, int);

int main(void) {
  mmk_mock("exit@self", exit_mock);

  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  mmk_reset(exit);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with the following on macOS 11:
`clang -I ./include -g -rpath ./lib/ -Wl,-segalign,1000 -L ./lib/ -l mimick -o test test.c`
Where mimick is already compiled and installed to `./lib` and `./include`.

Running with: `lldb ./test`

lldb gives me:

```
(lldb) target create "test"
Current executable set to '/Users/camdennarzt/Developer/C/test/test' (x86_64).
(lldb) r
Process 94625 launched: '/Users/camdennarzt/Developer/C/test/test' (x86_64)
Process 94625 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
    frame #0: 0x00007fff20531c9e libdyld.dylib`stack_not_16_byte_aligned_error
libdyld.dylib`stack_not_16_byte_aligned_error:
->  0x7fff20531c9e <+0>: movdqa %xmm0, (%rsp)
    0x7fff20531ca3 <+5>: int3   
    0x7fff20531ca4 <+6>: nop    
    0x7fff20531ca5 <+7>: nop    
Target 0: (test) stopped.
(lldb) bt
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff20531c9e libdyld.dylib`stack_not_16_byte_aligned_error
    frame #1: 0x00007ffeefbfefc8
    frame #2: 0x0000000100001941 test`mmk_mock_create_internal + 289
    frame #3: 0x0000000100003315 test`mmkuser_exit_mock_create(tgt="\x80&", opts=(sentinel_ = 0, noabort = 0)) at test.c:4:1
    frame #4: 0x00000001001ae010
    frame #5: 0x00007fff20532f3d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #6: 0x00007fff20532f3d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Because I saw [this](https://twitter.com/fxcoudert/status/1244299269068251137?lang=en) I also tried compiling with `-fno-stack-check -mmacosx-version-min=10.14` but it didn't help. I also tried with a homebrew installed clang but that didn't help either.

What am I doing wrong here? Or is there a bug in a library/compiler I'm using?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Criterion/Mimick so this may/may not make a difference.

If `params[i].argv` is to mimic `main()`'s `argv`, then `.argv[argc]` as `NULL` is missing.

> `argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer.
> C17 Spec.

```
params[0].argc = 1; 
params[0].argv = cr_malloc(sizeof(char*) * 2 /* not 1 */);
params[0].argv[0] = cr_strdup("progname"); 
params[0].argv[1] = NULL; /* add */
```

Likewise for other `params[i]` and `free_parse_args()` needs update.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't the issue.